# Can I use the access token directly from FB.login on my server?

Tags: facebook, security, oauth

I'd like to implement a Facebook authentication that does not perform traditional oauth redirects. It doesn't play nicely with my single-page-application and GraphQL API.

On the JS side, I can invoke `FB.login` to trigger a dialog for the user to login. If this is successful, I receive an object containing an `accessToken` and a `signedRequest`.

`signedRequest` can be decoded on the server and it spits out a `code` for me. I can use `code` with `/oauth/access_token` to get an `accessToken`.

However, I already had the `accessToken` this whole time from the `FB.login` response. So my question is: **is there any point of me decoding the signed request, if I had the access token this whole time?**

Bonus: Why does the FB API provide a signed request in the first place, and why does the oauth redirect by default forward the `code` and not an `accessToken`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use the token you got from the client-side login, directly on the server.

It might however be a short-lived one, whereas the server-side login flow should give you a long-lived one right away. If you only need to perform API calls while the user is active on your page, the short-lived one will probably do. (And it could still be exchanged for a long-lived one with a server-side API call, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing)

> Why does the FB API provide a signed request in the first place

It also contains a bit more info, that might be useful for a client-side app (user id, token expiry, externally passed in data in case of the old “Canvas” type apps), and might save on one additional API call to get that kind of info. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/

> and why does the oauth redirect by default forward the code and not an accessToken?

General security measure. The token contained directly in the return URL, could easily be stolen by 3rd-party scripts that might be embedded on that page (ad servers etc. can get hacked from time to time, too), or leaked as part of the HTTP referrer.
The `code` parameter requires your app secret for the API call that exchanges it for a token, so if the code were to leak in any such way, whoever else got their hands on it, can’t do anything with it.